# woocommerce_quantity_input() not working on shop page woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a code snippet that is supposed to add a quantity dropdown to the product category and the shop page.

Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        // Get the necessary classes
        $class = implode( ' ', array_filter( array(
            'button',
            'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
            $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
            $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
        ) ) );

    $html = sprintf( '%s%s<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>%s',
    '<form class="cart">',
    woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false ),
    esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
    esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
    esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
    esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
    esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
    esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ),
    '</form>'
    );
return $html;
}

add_action( 'wp_footer' , 'archives_quantity_fields_script' );
function archives_quantity_fields_script(){
if( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ): ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(function($){
            // Update quantity on 'a.button' in 'data-quantity' attribute (for ajax)
            $(".add_to_cart_button.product_type_simple").on('click', function() { var $button = $(this); $button.data('quantity', $button.parent().find('input.qty').val()); });        
            // remove old "view cart" text, only need latest one thanks!
            $(document.body).on("adding_to_cart", function() {
                $("a.added_to_cart").remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php endif;
}}
```

The above code works as expected on the Product Category page and shows the quantity dropdown (see images).

[image: Working on Product Category Page]

Here is how it looks in the page source:

[image]

However, on the Shop page, the select does not show up:

[image]

In the source, the form is correctly being added from the code snippet, however, `woocommerce_quantity_input()` is not outputting even the div with the `class='quantity'`.

[image]

I must be missing something really easy, but this has been doing my head in!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` hook. You should also not define the `wp_footer` hook inside this function. woocommerce automatically performs Ajax operations.

The following code is all you need:

```
<?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart', 11 );
function quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {

        // Remove default add to cart button
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );

        // Get the necessary classes
        $class = implode( ' ', array_filter( array(
            'button',
            'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
            $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
            $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
        ) ) );

        $html = sprintf( '%s%s<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>%s',
                        '<form class="cart">',
                            woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false ),
                            esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
                            esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
                            esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
                            esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
                            esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
                            esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ),
                        '</form>'
        );

        echo  $html;
    }
}
```

Code goes in the `functions.php` file of your active theme/child theme. Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you so much. It managed to work but only when I put  ! is_shop(). But at least it works